# Telerik RadListBox, transfer item through code

Tags: telerik, radlistbox

Ok I just want to know if what I am thinking of is even possible. I have tried researching but was not able to find anything. I have two RadLsitBox that I can transfer data between. I want to know if I could add an Undo button that could undo the last transfer I make.

FYI Client wants an undo button. I do not think this is possible to pass items only through code without pressing the buttons but if someone has a way I would like to hear.

```
 <telerik:RadListBox ID="rlbStations" runat="server" AllowTransfer="True" TransferToID="rlbAllowedStations"
                            Height="200px" Skin="Web20" SelectionMode="Multiple" Sort="Ascending" DataKeyField="station_id"
                            AutoPostBackOnTransfer="true" Width="250px" OnTransferred="rlbStations_Transferred">
                            <ButtonSettings ShowDelete="False" ShowReorder="False" />
                        </telerik:RadListBox>

                        <telerik:RadListBox ID="rlbAllowedStations" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="250px"
                            Skin="Web20">
                        </telerik:RadListBox>
```

EDIT: Add javascript

```
 var UndoList = new Array();
    function onClientTransferring(sender, e) {
        var items = e.get_items();
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            if (item.get_text() != "Select" || item.get_value() != "") {
                UndoList.push(item);
                UndoList.push(e.get_sourceListBox());
                UndoList.push(e.get_destinationListBox());
                sender.transferItem(item, e.get_sourceListBox(),e.get_destinationListBox());
            }
        }

    }

    function undoChanges() {
        if (UndoList[UndoList.length - 1]._clientStateFieldID == "rlbStations_ClientState") {
        var listbox = $find('rlbStations');
        }
    else if (UndoList[UndoList.length - 1]._clientStateFieldID == "rlbAllowedStations_ClientState") {
        var listbox = $find('rlbAllowedStations');
        }
        listbox.transferItem(UndoList[UndoList.length - 3], UndoList[UndoList.length - 2], UndoList[UndoList.length - 1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: yes!  You can transfer items without using the built-in transfer buttons.  Here is a code sample using JavaScript as an example:

```
function onClientTransferring(sender, e) {debugger
   //cancel the event
   e.set_cancel(true);
   //manually transfer the appropriate items
   var items = e.get_items();
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       var item = items[i];
       if (item.get_text() != "Select" || item.get_value() != "") {
           sender.transferItem(item, e.get_sourceListBox(), e.get_destinationListBox());
       }
   }
}
```

And the `RadListBox`:

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListBox1"
   runat="server"
   Skin="Vista"
   AllowTransfer="true"   
   TransferToID="RadListBox2"
   DataKeyField="ID"  
   OnClientTransferring="onClientTransferring"
   DataTextField="Name"
   DataValueField="ID"       
   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >    
</telerik:RadListBox>
<telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListBox2" runat="server"
   Skin="Vista"
   AllowTransfer="true">
```

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/listbox-how-to-transfer-specific-items-with-transferall-button.html

Comment: I just tried this code and it does use the built in transfer buttons.

Comment: I tried using it for another button but it it won't even hit that code. Even the article you linked to makes no mention of not using the default transfer buttons.

Comment: You need to call onClientTransferring yourself from another button or whatever you choose. This was just example code, not a final solution.

Comment: I thought your question was about adding an undo mechanism?  You can do it with the code I provided and the built in buttons. Every time an item is transferred, store it's value in some list. If a user clicks your Undo button, transfer that item back to the original list.

Comment: Except when I added onClientTransferring to my Undo button it wouldn't do anything. It wouldn't transfer the item back to the list it came from.

Comment: I see... yes, this wasn't meant as a fully functioning piece of code for you.  I was just providing an example that you can programmatically transfer items.  Sorry for the confusion on my part.  But from the example you can see how it's transferring the item right?  sender.transferItem()

Comment: But in this example sender is the listbox. If I have this code being run from clicking a button the sender would be the button and would not have access to tranfserItem correct?

Comment: You can specify a listbox when you call the function.  var listbox = $find('<%=listbox.ClientID%>'); listbox.transferItem(...)

Comment: ok I see what you are saying now. I am just trying to think now How I am going to track the changes simply because all of this code is mainly server side code and not client side.

Comment: Working with server side code should be just as easy.  You can hook the OnTransferred event to record which item was transferred.  http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/listbox-transferring-event.html.  Then for your undo button you can just remove the item from one listbox and add it back to the other http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/listbox-working-with-items-server-side.html

Comment: Well I actually almost have the client side stuff set up but thanks for those articles. I am get a null error in the dynamic code for the telerik control. Not to sure whats going wrong now.

Comment: This works but we decided to go with a much faster way. To just cancel